# Only store item in list if different from the first or last item

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I've got a multidimensional list like this:

[[1525815456, 2],[1525815487, 3],[1525815517, 2],[1525815547, 2],[1525815577, 2],[1525815608, 4],[1525815638, 4]]

How can I loop through it and delete any lists in the list where the second value is the same as either the last or next second value but not both? So that the list above would change to this:

[[1525815456, 2],[1525815487, 3],[1525815517, 2],[1525815577, 2],[1525815608, 4],[1525815638, 4]]

I have already tried something like this:

```
for idx in range(len(data)-1):
    x = data[idx]
    if data[idx][1] != data[idx-1][1] and data[idx][1] == data[idx+1][1]:
        newdata.append(x)
    if data[idx][1] != data[idx+1][1] and data[idx][1] == data[idx-1][1]:
        newdata.append(x)
    if data[idx][1] != data[idx+1][1] and data[idx][1] != data[idx-1][1]:
        newdata.append(x)
```

But I keep getting errors and cannot get it to work.

Edit:

Thanks everyone, here's the code:

```
data = [[1, 2],[2, 3],[3, 2],[4, 2],[5, 2],[6, 4],[7, 4]]
newdata = []
for idx in range(len(data)-1):
    x = data[idx]
    if idx != 0 and idx != len(data)-1:
        if data[idx][1] != data[idx-1][1] or data[idx][1] != data[idx+1][1]:
            newdata.append(x)
    else:
        newdata.append(x)
newdata.append(data[-1])
print newdata
```

will return:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [5, 2], [6, 4], [7, 4]]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make the connection between your explanation, the example and the code. Try to explain the rule more clearly, give an example which is easier to read (these very large numbers don't help), and include in your question the complete error message you got.

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting rid of `[1525815517, 2]`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  It should keep every list in the list where the second value of the inside list is different to either the one before it or the one after it. Also the very large numbers are just Unix time stamps, they don't affect the rule, the rule is only about the second number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule #1 of containers:

> Do **not** modify the container while you iterate over it

You've already got the right idea by appending to a new container, so kudos to you.

As I understand it, the conditions are:

1. The element's 2nd item **can** equal the previous element's 2nd item
2. The element's 2nd item **can** equal the next element's 2nd item
3. The element's 2nd item **cannot** equal both the previous and next element's 2nd item

Because of these conditions we know that the first and last element of the initial list will always be included in the new list (unless you are circularly checking a list...which changes this...) since they have no preceding or trailing element respectively. Thus we only need to check the elements between the first and last elements for their preceding and trailing element's 2nd item.

Here is how I would solve it:

```
data = [
         [1525815456, 2],
         [1525815487, 3],
         [1525815517, 2],
         [1525815547, 2],
         [1525815577, 2],
         [1525815608, 4],
         [1525815638, 4]
       ]

newdata = []
num = len(data)
for i in range(num):
    prv = i - 1
    nxt = i + 1
    if prv < 0:
        # first element in list, can always stay
        newdata.append(data[i])
    elif nxt == num:
        # last element in list, can always stay
        newdata.append(data[i])
    else:
        # all other elements between
        # condition is only remove those that match prv and nxt
        if (data[i][1] != data[prv][1]) or (data[i][1] != data[nxt][1]):
            newdata.append(data[i])


for ele in newdata:
    print(ele)

# Outputs:
# [1525815456, 2]
# [1525815487, 3]
# [1525815517, 2]
# [1525815577, 2]
# [1525815608, 4]
# [1525815638, 4]
```

Demo as run on [ideone](https://ideone.com/pV9y14)

Comment: Thank you very much, Excellent answer! The only thing is that this misses out the last item in the list, not sure why, but I just added newdata.append(data[-1]) to the end of mine...

Comment: @mastercooker I'd have to see your implementation, the last element should not be dropped. The `elif nxt == num` checks to see if the next element would be large than the list indices (i.e. `len(data)`), and if so, that means your current `i` must be `data[len(data) - 1]`.

Comment: @mastercooker I made an update in the final `if` to be `or` not `and`, I also attached a link showing that it works as you described it should.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you can't access `data[idx-1]` when `idx=0`. Same with the last element and `data[idx+1]`.
So add a check, `if idx == 0 or idx == len(data)`.
If you're having other errors, it would be great if you could post the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help